# add a delete button for every record in a bootstrap table in PUG

Tags: html, express, pug

I am trying to add a button for every record in a bootstrap table i am using a pug templating engine.its seems that the  tag not working.Please help

```
.jumbotron
  h1 User Report
.container
  table.table
    thead
      tr
        th(scope='col') Name
        th(scope='col') Student ID
        th(scope='col') Department
        th(scope='col') Edit
    tbody
    each x,i in info
        tr
          th(scope='row')= x.name
          td= x.studentID
          td= x.dept
          td= input.btn.btn-primary(id='info.id', type='button', value='Delete')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to nest the `input` within the `td`, indent the `input` under the `td` like this:

```
.jumbotron
    h1 User Report
.container
    table.table
        thead
            tr
                th(scope='col') Name
                th(scope='col') Student ID
                th(scope='col') Department
                th(scope='col') Edit
        tbody
          each x,i in info
            tr
                th(scope='row')= x.name
                td= x.studentID
                td= x.dept
                td
                    input.btn.btn-primary(id= info.id, type='button', value='Delete')
```